# My npm package installs "extraneous" dependencies

Tags: npm

I'm trying to publish a javascript library with npm.

When I first installed it, then tried to run `npm ls` I see "extraneous" warnings on each of its dependencies:

```
├─┬ krousel@0.1.0
│ ├── http-server@0.12.1 extraneous
│ ├── husky@4.2.3 extraneous
│ ├── lint-staged@10.0.7 extraneous
│ ├── microbundle@0.11.0 extraneous
│ ├── node-sass@4.13.1 extraneous
│ ├── prettier@1.19.1 extraneous
│ └── sass@1.26.3 extraneous
```

I'd like to fix this but I have no idea what I did wrong

all of these are devDependencies that are not required when you are a user of the lib, I don't know why they were installed.

source code: https://github.com/VincentCharpentier/krousel

npm link: https://www.npmjs.com/package/krousel

the package.json of the library:

```
{
  "name": "krousel",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "Carousel library",
  "source": "src/index.js",
  "main": "dist/krousel.js",
  "module": "dist/krousel.module.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "microbundle --name Krousel",
    "watch": "microbundle watch --name Krousel",
    "watch:examples": "parcel ./examples/index.html --out-dir public --open",
    "build:examples": "parcel build ./examples/index.html --out-dir docs --public-url ./",
    "serve:examples": "http-server docs -p 8082",
    "prettier": "prettier --write src/*"
  },
  "targets": "> 0.25%, not dead",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/VincentCharpentier/krousel.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "carousel",
    "slider",
    "javascript"
  ],
  "author": "Vincent Charpentier",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/VincentCharpentier/krousel/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/VincentCharpentier/krousel#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "http-server": "0.12.1",
    "husky": "4.2.3",
    "lint-staged": "10.0.7",
    "microbundle": "0.11.0",
    "node-sass": "4.13.1",
    "prettier": "1.19.1",
    "sass": "1.26.3"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "src/**/*.js": "prettier --write"
  }
}
```

I tried running `npm prune` in the directory where I installed it but this isn't fixing the problem